# RecyclerView и View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Привет, 
мне кажется я что-то не так понимаю, почему при долгом нажатии, после обработки OnLongClick обрабатывается OnClick. Не ужели надо делать проверку в OnClick чтобы он его ошибочно не запускал? такой вариант похож на костыль, и не вполне удачный.

```
package com.fgurbanov.skynet.Tasklintent.Fragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fgurbanov.skynet.Tasklintent.TaskPagerActivity;
import com.fgurbanov.skynet.Tasklintent.Data.Task;
import com.fgurbanov.skynet.Tasklintent.Data.TaskLab;
import com.fgurbanov.skynet.Tasklintent.R;

import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;

import static android.widget.CompoundButton.*;


public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment {

//private static final int REQUEST_CRIME = 1;

private static final String SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE = "subtitle";
private static final String SAVED_SCREEN_VIEWS = "grid_view";
private static final String SAVED_SELECT_MODE = "select_mode";

private RecyclerView mTaskRecyclerView;
private TaskAdapter mAdapter;

private TextView mEmptyNotifyTextView;

private int mChangedPosition;

private boolean mSubtitleVisible;
private boolean mGridListView;
private boolean mSelectMode;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_list, container, false);
    mTaskRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_recycler_view);
    mTaskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    mEmptyNotifyTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_notify_text_view);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean
                (SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
        mGridListView = savedInstanceState.getBoolean
                (SAVED_SCREEN_VIEWS);
        mSelectMode = savedInstanceState.getBoolean
                (SAVED_SELECT_MODE);
    }

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE, mSubtitleVisible);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SCREEN_VIEWS, mGridListView);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SELECT_MODE, mSelectMode);
}


//Menu options
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_task_list, menu);

    MenuItem subtitleItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle);
    if (mSubtitleVisible) {
        subtitleItem.setTitle(R.string.hide_subtitle);
    } else {
        subtitleItem.setTitle(R.string.show_subtitle);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_item_new_task:
            Task task = new Task();
            TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);
            Intent intent  = TaskPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), task.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle:
            mSubtitleVisible = !mSubtitleVisible;
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            updateSubtitle();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_delete_list:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_switch_view:
            mGridListView = !mGridListView;
            changeListView();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void updateSubtitle(){
    TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.get(getActivity());

    int taskSize = taskLab.getTasks().size();
    String subtitle = getResources()
            .getQuantityString(R.plurals.subtitle_plural, taskSize, taskSize);

    if (!mSubtitleVisible) {
        subtitle = null;
    }

    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
}

public void changeListView() {
    if (mGridListView){
        mTaskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager
                (getActivity(), 2));
    } else {
        mTaskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }
    //TODO: calculate the dimension of the grid
}


private void updateUI() {
    TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.get(getActivity());
    List<Task> tasks = taskLab.getTasks();

    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(tasks);
        mTaskRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        //mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(mChangedPosition);
        mAdapter.setTasks(tasks);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    if (tasks.size() == 0){
        mEmptyNotifyTextView.setText( getString(R.string.notify_empty_list) );
        mEmptyNotifyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mEmptyNotifyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    changeListView();
    updateSubtitle();
}



private class TaskHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    private Task mTask;



    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_title_text_view);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_date_text_view);
        mSolvedCheckBox= (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_solved_check_box);

        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // Set Flag of solved crime
                mTask.setSolved(isChecked);

                TaskLab.get(getActivity())
                        .updateTask(mTask);
            }
        });

    }

    public void bindTask(Task task){
        mTask = task;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mTask.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(mTask.getDateString());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mTask.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mChangedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        if (!mSelectMode) {
            Intent intent = TaskPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mTask.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Selected  " + mTask.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        mSelectMode = !mSelectMode;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select mode \n Item Selected  " + mTask.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }


}


private class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder>
{
    private List<Task> mTasks;

    public TaskAdapter(List<Task> tasks){
        this.mTasks = tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {
        Task task = mTasks.get(position);
        holder.bindTask(task);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTasks.size();
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks){
        mTasks = tasks;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    mSelectMode = !mSelectMode;
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select mode \n Item Selected  " + mTask.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Или если вам нужно в каких-то случаях обрабатывать onClick вместо onLongClick, то в onLongClick нужно вернуть `false` только для этих случаев.