# Java Разные виды нажатия events на одном объекте

Tags: java

У меня есть TextView при нажатии(долго onLongClick) на который он должен выделяться,а при простом клике( onClick) меняться на другой.

Проблема заключается в то, что после добавления onClick - не распознается долгое нажатие и начинается евент простого клика.

---

Как реализовать на одном объекте разные ивенты?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598809/recyclerview-%D0%B8-view-onclicklistener-view-onlongclicklistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из листенера onLongClickверните значение true. Это будет говорить о том, что клик уже обработан и нет необходимости другим листенерам его обрабатывать.

Вот тут вы можете посмотреть подробнее
https://workingdev.net/android,/kotlin/2018/08/01/handling-clicks-and-long-clicks.html